# Slack notification from lambda not breaking message in newline

Tags: python, aws-lambda, slack

I am using below code to send message to slack from aws lambda, need to have newline between first and second variable. Both of them are of string type.
Message received on slack is on single line - first second
I need output on slack as
first
second
Can someone help!!

```
msg = {
        "text" : first+'\n'+second
        
    }
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST',hook_url, body=encoded_msg)
```

Comment: This is an old problem  - https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/slack-step-does-not-treat-n-as-a-newline-when-message-generated-by-a-bash-script-step/1776/12  and https://github.com/cleentfaar/slack/issues/21 try "\n" using double quotes instead of single

Comment: Thanks Joseph , your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "type": "mrkdwn",
  "text": first + '\n' + second
}
```

Refer to this: https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/composition-objects#text

Slack has introduced Block Kit, and now type is introduced as `mrkdwn` where you can modify the text as per the requirements.